# Specialized Page Template Not Showing Up - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a strange situation. I created [specialized page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Specialized_Page_Template) for my WordPress site and it works perfectly for the first specialized page that I created, but when I created the second one on my site, the page ends up being blank, no title, no favicon, no content, etc. Does anyone know why this would be happening and how to fix it?

**I have verified the following:**

- The page-{ID}.php is in the root of the child/template folder
- The file name is spelled correctly
- There isn't another page template assigned to the page in the WordPress UI (only the default template)
- Cleared my cache

I have tried switching to another theme and back to see if that will fix it, but it does not.

**Pages for your reference:**

- Here is the site: http://goo.gl/xBC6a1
- Here is the custom page (that works): http://goo.gl/2t5j7o
- Here is the broken page: http://goo.gl/lWBwNp

Let me know if you have any suggestions that I can troubleshoot with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you turned on error logging, and is there anything in the php error log?

Comment: WordPress isn't reporting any errors, I checked the debug.log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I didn't add the necessary PHP code to launch the parent theme in that page file. That cured the problem.

Comment: It was the Genesis Framework by StudioPress and the missing code was: "<?php genesis(); ?>" without quotes of course.